# If $L\cdot\{\epsilon,0\}$ regular language, is $L$ regular?

Tags: automata, regular-language

I've encountered a question during my studies:
If $L\cdot\{\epsilon,0\}$ regular language, is $L$ regular?

I thought to disprove it by using $A\subseteq 2\mathbb{N}, L=\{w\in\{0\}^*:|w|\notin A\}$ but I need to prove that L is irregular and using the pumping lemma in my proof is forbidden.
Any help?

Comment: Whether or not your $L$ is regular depends on $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, but if I choose for example: $A=\{2^i : i=0,1,2..\}$ (is it Ok?) then how can I prove that $L$ is irregular?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Myhill-Nerode theorem?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No, we can't use that either.
Do you have a more simple example for $A$ ?

Comment: If you’re not allowed to use the basic tools, you may not be able to give an explicit example. You could, however, argue that $2\Bbb N$ has uncountably many subsets, but there are only countably many regular expressions over a given alphabet, so ...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I didn't quite understand how can I use this fact in the question.. can you please explain a little more?

Comment: There are uncountably many languages $L_A=\{w\in\{0\}^*:|w\notin A\}$ for $A\subseteq 2\Bbb N$, but only countably many of them are regular, since there are only countably many regular expressions over the alphabet $\{0\}$, so there must be subsets $A\subseteq 2\Bbb N$ such that $L_A$ is not regular. (I’m not convinced that this actually helps you, since I don’t think that $L_A\cdot\{\epsilon,0\}$ is regular, but it is what you asked for originally.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why does $L_A \cdot \{ \epsilon , 0 \} $ not regular? Do you have an example to disprove the original question?

Comment: You’re right: I just hadn’t thought it through completely. Yes, this will work fine, and I’ll convert my cardinality argument to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re not allowed to use basic tools like the pumping lemma and the Myhill-Nerode theorem, the only thing that I can suggest is a cardinality argument. There are only countably many regular expressions over the alphabet $\{0\}$, so there are only countably many regular languages that are subsets of $\{0\}^*$. However, there are uncountably many subsets $A\subseteq 2\Bbb N$, and each gives rise to a different language $L_A=\{w\in\{0\}^*:|w|\notin A\}$, so there must be an $A\subseteq 2\Bbb N$ such that $L_A$ is not regular.

Comment: How does this help? $L_A$ is not regular, sure, but why $L_A\cdot\{\varepsilon,0\}$ is?

Comment: @sas: $L_A\cdot\{\epsilon\}=L_A$ contains all $w\in\{0\}^*$ of odd length, so $L_A\cdot\{0\}$ contains all $w\in\{0\}^*$ of positive even length, so $L_A\cdot\{\epsilon,0\}\supseteq\{0\}^*\setminus\{\epsilon\}$. If $0\in A$, then $\epsilon\notin L_A$, and $L_A\cdot\{\epsilon,0\}=\{0\}^*\setminus\{\epsilon\}$, and if $0\notin A$, then $\epsilon\in L_A$, and $L_A\cdot\{\epsilon,0\}=\{0\}^*$; both of these languages are regular.

Comment: Omg, I've read it wrong. $|w|\not\in A$, sure, that makes sense. Thank you. I could suggest $L$ be the language of all words over $\{0,1\}$ that are not of the form $1^n0^n$. This is essentially the same but with a reference to "canonical" irregular language.